# Parsing HTML Table based on nearby header tag using DOMDocument and DOMXPath

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument, domxpath

I have a simple PHP app that parse html content and extract data from **td** that matches certain query.

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
    <h3>HELLO WORLD</h3>
    <table>
         <tr><td>A</td><td>A2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>B</td><td>B2</td></tr>
         ...
         ...
    </table>
    <h3>HELLO AMERICA</h3>
    <table>
         <tr><td>A</td><td>A3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>C</td><td>C2</td></tr>
         ...
         ...
    </table>
    <h3>HELLO TEXAS</h3>
    <table>
         <tr><td>D</td><td>D2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>E</td><td>E2</td></tr>
         ...
         ...
    </table>
<html>
```

**PHP Code to parse the table**

```
$content = file_get_contents($html_string);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = "//tr/td[position()=1 and normalize-space(text()) = '".$q."']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

$entryCount = $entries->length;

if ($entryCount==1){
    $entry = $entries->item(0);
    $tr = $entry->parentNode;
    foreach ($tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td) {
        $fieldnames[] = $td->textContent;
    }

//Return data set
    $data[] = $fieldnames;
    return $data;
}

else {
    $data = array();

    for ($i=0;$i<$entryCount;$i++){
        $fieldnames = [];
        $entry = $entries->item($i);
        $tr = $entry->parentNode;
        foreach ($tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td) {
            $fieldnames[] = $td->textContent;
        }
        $data[] = $fieldnames;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Basically this will go through all 3 tables. Let say, I send a query ($q = A), it will return:

> $data[0][0] => A, $data[0][1] => A2
>   $data[1][0] => A, $data[1][1] => A3

However, I only want the data from the first table (A and A2). The table is 'naked'. No ID, no class or any identification. The only thing that identifies them is the **h3** tag. Let say, I provide a query that specifies the **h3** ($q2 = HELLO WORLD), is it possible to extract data from only the first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the preceding-sibling axis and the `[1]` positional predicate (or whatever it’s formally called), and look at the text content of the `h3` elements to find whichever `h3` element is the one right before the `table` you want; so, I think, this:

```
//table[preceding-sibling::h3[1][. = "HELLO WORLD"]]
```

Or, to get the specific stuff within that which the code in your example is looking for,

```
//table[preceding-sibling::h3[1][. = "HELLO WORLD"]]/tr/td[position()=1 and normalize-space(text()) = '".$q."']
```

And if you did later happen to want to get any of the other tables, just swap out the text in that expression; for example, the following will get just the last one in your example.

```
//table[preceding-sibling::h3[1][. = "HELLO TEXAS"]]
```